# project onto a span of not orthogonal elements.

Tags: functional-analysis

If span {$u_1, u_2, ... u_n$} consists of orthogonal vectors then projection onto that subspace is just the projection on each of the orthogonal elements. How would one project if the elements were not orthogonal?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Formulas

Comment: One can start by using the Gram–Schmidt procedure to convert the set of vectors into an orthonormal basis for its span.

Comment: I was thinking to just set it up as an explicit optimization problem, since I am dealing with function spaces.